# best way to create a non sudo "guest" user with access only to specific applications/services/libraries in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, users, group, administration

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 with two user accounts:

- admin (member of sudo group, initial installed user)
- guest (not member of sudo group), it's home directory mounted on a separate partition.

I wish to use the admin user to install some applications/services/libraries using the apt service and grant the guest user the ability to use some of these apps/services/libraries without the ability to use others nor other system resources.
What is the right way of doing that?
I wish to use a "whitelist" approach , hence the guest will able to access only strictly specified resources.

1. Should I use the admin user to download the relevant stuff to the guest home directory and install them there?

1.b. Is it possible to download/install stuff into specific locations using the apt-get and is it right to do so?

2. Should I download/install the apps/services/libraries regularly and create specific group containing the guest user that can access them?

2.b. How can I grant several different groups the ability to access/use specific apps/services/libraries

3.Does my use case is generally possible (create non sudo user with limited access to apps/services/libraries)?

I'm asking that because maybe when i install something on my system it creates files in many places throughout the system hence I cannot grant access to specific apps/services/libraries based on directories and/or groups without being members of sudo group.

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question: 1. Are you looking for a [blacklist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blacklist_(computing)) approach (guest can run all commands except for the ones you explicitly block for him) or [whitelist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist) approach (all commands are denied for guest by default, except for the ones you explicitly allow). 2. Do the commands you want to allow require root access for running? Or they do not require any special privilege? 3. _"other system resources"_ - what kind of resources? Please [edit] your question with those clarifications.